# AngularJS + Jasmine unit test Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am leanring unit testing with angular and jasmine. I am getting the following error when running the tests:

> Result Message:   Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr...

**Unit Test**

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/_references.js" />
/// <reference path="jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="SampleController.js" />

describe('Controller Unit Test: ', function () {
    var scope, ctrl, $timeout;
    var someServiceMock;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        someServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('someService', ['someAsyncCall']);
        inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q, _$timeout_) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            someServiceMock.someAsyncCall.andReturn($q.when('weee'));
            $timeout = _$timeout_;
            ctrl = $controller('SampleController', {
                $scope: scope,
                someService: someServiceMock
            });
        });
    });

    it('Controller exists', function () {
        expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('SampleController', function ($scope, someService) {

    //set some properties
    $scope.foo = 'foo';
    $scope.bar = 'bar';

    //add a simple function.
    $scope.test1 = function () {
        $scope.foo = $scope.foo + '!!!';
    };

    //set up a $watch.
    $scope.$watch('bar', function (v) {
        $scope.baz = v + 'baz';
    });

    //make a call to an injected service.
    $scope.test2 = function () {
        someService.someAsyncCall($scope.foo)
          .then(function (data) {
              $scope.fizz = data;
          });
    };
});

app.factory('someService', function ($timeout, $q) {
    return {

        // simple method to do something asynchronously.
        someAsyncCall: function (x) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve(x + '_async');
            }, 100);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

**finally, my reference files:**

```
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-animate.min.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-sanitize.min.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-route.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-2.1.1.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.min.js" />
/// <reference path="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js" />
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.8.3.js" />
```

When I set a break point within the inject function in the test and run debugging mode, it nevers goes into it.

Comment: You don't have a reference to your controller file in your list of references inside your unit test file at the top. Order also matters, make sure it is the last file referenced.

Comment: Sorry, it was in there but I pulled it out in an attempt to try things. I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your test code like so, I also took the liberty of modying your structure so that way your tests might be a bit more efficient. For smaller controllers / tests it does not matter but  for more complex functionality the ability to reset for a test set makes this easier.

The 1st `beforeEach` will inject `$injector` into the function which you can use to get your  references. This can be done in the main `describe` function as they will likely not change.

The 2nd `beforeEach` I have nested in a new `describe` function. You can then create a batched set of tests where each `it` is guaranteed a fresh/new controller instance.

If `$injector` is null or undefined it means that the scripts are not being loaded or being loaded in the wrong order. To better troubleshoot this you need to see what is failing the injection because Angular is not yet aware of it, in that case please comment with the full message/url like you started to at the top of your post and we can then put the references in the correct order.

**Controller file**

```
/// <reference path="jquery-2.1.1.min.js" />
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />
... rest of your code
```

**Unit test file**

```
/// <chutzpah_reference path="angular.min.js"/>
/// <chutzpah_reference path="angular-mocks.js"/>
// you might need additional chutzpah_reference but it really depends on your chutzpah configuration found in chutzpah.json
/// <reference path="jquery-2.1.1.min.js" />
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="SampleController.js" />

describe('Controller Unit Test: ', function () {
    var $rootScope;  //, $timeout;
    var someServiceMock;

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.module("app"); // mock your module
    });

    // setup
    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        someServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('someService', ['someAsyncCall']);
        someServiceMock.someAsyncCall.andReturn($q.when('weee'));

        var $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
        // $timeout = $injector.get("$timeout"); // not used anywhere that I can see
    }));

    describe('this will executes initial some set of tests on your controller', () => {
        var scope;
        var ctrl;
        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('SampleController', {
                $scope: scope,
                someService: someServiceMock});
        }));

        it('Controller exists', function () {
            expect(scope).toBeDefined();
            expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

**Edit 1**

Changed references. Added angular mock call.

Comment: I copied this into another test file and same error. When I break point it and hover over the scope and ctrl variables in the it() they are undefined. for what ever reason, the code never goes into the inject function block.

Comment: @steveareeno - I updated the code. Could you update your references accordingly and also make the call to mock module?

Comment: I tried that and even completely removed the services ref from the controller and unit test. Does it make any difference if I am using chutzpah in VS 2012?

Comment: @steveareeno - yes, that can make a big difference. You will need to include chutzpah references or make sure that chutzpah is aware of all the corresponding files so it can load everything. You should have probably included that in your original post. Give me a bit and I will see if I can update the references accordingly.

Comment: @steveareeno - If you need `chutzpah_reference` references or not in your unit test file depends very much on your chutzpah configuration found in `chutzpah.json` and your file layout. This could be a reason though that the injection is not working because chutzpah never copies the references for the unit test that it is executing. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I will keep playing around with it. I appreciate all your time. If I find out why it isn't working I'll be sure to post.

Comment: I downloaded the standalone version of jasmine and used spec runner and got it running. I found out that I was referencing 'app' instead of 'myApp' in my spec. However, I can't repo it because chutzpah no longer see the spec files in the other folder anymore. I think I will stay with just pure jasmine. chutzpah also kept crashing VS.

Comment: @steveareeno - chutzpah is good once you get it to work, its just the initial configuration that takes a while to get right. The upside of chutzpah is the VS integration with test runner and later on also integration with your build server if you run your unit tests as a part of continuous integration. It can crash VS if the config is off I think.